# Javascript/jQuery - if the value of the input is

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, operator-keyword

I want to make a working calculator.
Now, i want to change between the operators.

Let's say I have + and -. Then, I have 2 numbers. The operator is between them.

If the value of the operator is +, it should calculate +.
If the value of operator is -, it should calculate -.

I tried something like this but it doesnt work, help?

```
function Operator() {
            if ($('#realOperator').val == ('+');){
                    var a = parseInt($('input[name=a]').val());
                    var b = parseInt($('input[name=b]').val());
                    $('#total').val(a+b);
            }else
               $('#total').val(a-b);
            } 
        }
```

> **Information**
>
> #realOperator is the input with the operator
>
> #total is the input with the result.

Thanks and sorry if even the syntax is wrong.. I'm new!

Comment: Seems typo while posting. It should be `if($('#realOperator').val() == ('+'))` not `if ($('#realOperator').val == ('+');)`

Comment: Also the semicolon, and using a and b when they're not assigned, and the missing { after the else. There are *way* too many errors here, you must put some attention in your code.

Comment: but if i do if(.val() == ('+')) , how is it supposed to know it's for #realOperator

Comment: " Thanks and sorry if even the syntax is wrong.. I'm new! "

Comment: may have a look at eval...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution @Loris Vonlanthen

```
function Operator() {
    var a = parseInt($('input[name=a]').val());
    var b = parseInt($('input[name=b]').val());
    if ($('#realOperator').val() == '+') {
        $('#total').val(a + b);
    } else
        $('#total').val(a - b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, but the input named #total is empty

Comment: @Loris Vonlanthen check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkwsm9dz/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Shaybi , there might be another error in my code ugh..

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the semicolon in your condition, also, you need to set a and b outside of the if statement since your '-' code won't know what a and b are.

You also had a few syntax errors, which I've corrected for you below.

```
function Operator() {
    var a = parseInt($('input[name=a]').val(), 10);
    var b = parseInt($('input[name=b]').val(), 10);
    if ($('#realOperator').val() == ('+')){
        $('#total').val(a+b);
    } else {
        $('#total').val(a-b);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what does " , 10); " do?

Comment: It specifies the base to use in the parseInt() function. You can read more about this here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
function Operator() {
var a = parseInt($('input[name=a]').val());
var b = parseInt($('input[name=b]').val());
if ($('#realOperator').val() == ('+')) {
    var sum = a + b;
    $('#total').val(sum);
} else {
    if (a > b) {
        var minus = a - b;
    } else {
        var minus = b - a;
    }
    $('#total').val(minus);
  }
}
```

if you send code or input realOperator value then i will check again

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

there is semicolon (;) in between if statement.

Also you don't need to wrap brackets around operator like ('+'). You can just write '+'.

Also you have missed '{' with else but you have closed.

You should try this code:

```
function Operator() {
        if ($('#realOperator').val == '+'){
                var a = parseInt($('input[name=a]').val());
                var b = parseInt($('input[name=b]').val());
                $('#total').val(a+b);
        }else{
           $('#total').val(a-b);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. You have some syntax errors in your code, for example here:  `if ($('#realOperator').val == ('+');){`. The semicolon is unnecessary.
2. The method `.val()` will get you the value of input as **string**. You have to cast it to **number**.
3. It's better to separate your logic from your markup. So define your `Operator` function as a pure function which takes two numbers and one operator, and calculate the result.

```js
function operator(a, b, operation) {
  if (operation === '+') {
    return a + b;
  }
  else if (operation === '-') {
    return a - b;
  }
  
  // you can implement more operations like * / %
  
  throw new Error('Unhandled Operation');
}

$(function () {
  $('[data-role="operator"]').on('click', function () {
    var operation = $(this).text();
    var a = $('#a').val() * 1; // make it number
    var b = $('#b').val() * 1; // make it number
    
    $('#total').val( operator(a, b, operation) );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="a" type="text" />
<input id="b" type="text" />
<button data-role="operator">+</button>
<button data-role="operator">-</button>

<hr />
<input id="total" />
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'm a beginner and I'd like to use codes that are easier to understand like @Shaybi 's code